# Godot: Pause Menu does not load up the Main Menu properly

Tags: godot, gdscript

I've coded a Main Menu here with the following nodes: [(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpU6u.png)

- Two texture buttons
- Two Sprites
- And a tilemap

The issue here is that my main scene is the main menu scene which contains everything I've shown above. However, when I call this scene again, that is through the pause menu's "Go back to main menu" button, the scene loads but when I click on any of the buttons, it does not respond.

Here is my main menu code:

```
 extends Control

onready var Play_Button = get_node("Play Button")
onready var Exit_Button = get_node("Exit Button")
# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _grabonfirst(value):
    value.grab_focus()

func _ready():
    _grabonfirst(Play_Button)
    pass # Replace with function body.

func _process(delta):
    if Play_Button.pressed == true:
        get_tree().change_scene("res://Scenes/Tutorial.tscn")
    elif Exit_Button.pressed == true:
        get_tree().quit()
    pass
```

And my pause menu code is

```
extends Control

onready var main_menu_btn = get_node("Main Menu Btn")

func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("pause"):
        $"Continue Btn".grab_focus()
        get_tree().paused = not get_tree().paused
        visible = not visible

func _on_Continue_Btn_pressed():
    get_tree().paused = not get_tree().paused
    visible = not visible

func _on_Main_Menu_Btn_pressed():
    get_tree().change_scene("res://Scenes/Main Menu.tscn")# Replace with function body.
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when you go back to the main menu the game is still paused. Suggested fix:

```
func _on_Main_Menu_Btn_pressed():
    get_tree().paused = false
    get_tree().change_scene(...)
```